# How can I add related entity to many-to-many relation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Let's imagine I have such entities:

```
    public class Game
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }       

        public ICollection<GamePlatform> GamePlatforms { get; set; }

        // ↓ This one should be filled ↓
        public ICollection<Platform> Platforms { get; set; }
        // ↑ This one should be filled ↑
    }

    public class Platform
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }       

        public ICollection<GamePlatform> GamePlatforms { get; set; }

        // ↓ This one should be filled ↓
        public ICollection<Game> Games { get; set; }
        // ↑ This one should be filled ↑
    }

    public class GamePlatform
    {
        public int GameId { get; set; }
        public Game Game { get; set; }

        public int PlatformId { get; set; }
        public Platform Platform { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to avoid creating an extra entity and/or backend code.
Can I do so just via configuring in **OnModelCreating** method?

Comment: And because EF does not support many-to-many relationships fully yet, I'd suggest adding a PK to the GamePlatform class (for example, "GamePlatformId"). Otherwise, the Key will need to specified in the OnModelCreating method (for example, "mb.Entity<GamePlatform>().HasKey(k => new { k.GameId, k.PlatformId });").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think best practice is to create another entity. it can help you managing indexes and other things.